Problem in understanding why do we 'select' or 'arrange' in a specific arrangement
I have difficulty in understanding the concepts of 'selecting' and 'arranging' I had the doubt when I was previously solving a question which goes as follows :-
Given there are 10 lines drawn in a plane then calculate the number of intersection points
As far as the solution is concerned, it says
The number of intersection points of the 10 lines are equal to the number of ways of 'selecting' 2 objects from 10 objects
Then it goes on to give $^1{^0}C_2$
I do know that 'selection' means using $^nC_r$ but this is more or less a mugged up thing what is the intuitive explanation of 'selecting' and arranging

How good is your understanding of set theory? These things generally have very rigorous formulations expressed in set theory language, although not many students in a discrete math course have the required understanding of set theory.

@LeeMosher I do have quite good understanding also the book I read has some limited explanations that are mostly vague there was one part on why do this and that but it was vague and used English that would best be found in a Shakespearean drama

Assuming your understanding of set theory is solid, then you could translate "the number of ways of selecting $k$ objects from $n$ objects" into the language of set theory as "the number of $k$ object subsets of a set of $n$ objects".
The reason for the "selection" language is that it describes intuitively how a person might actually specify one particular $k$ object subset of a set of $n$ objects: just select $k$ of those $n$ objects.
"Arranging" has a similar intuitive meaning, first select the $k$ objects, then lay them out in a particular order. For the rigorous meaning, the number of arrangements of $k$ objects from a set of $n$ objects is the number of different sequences of the form $x_1,...,x_k$ such that each $x_i$ is an element of the given set of $n$ objects, and $x_i \ne x_j$ if $i \ne j$.

thanks a lot for that explanation now its much more clear also can you pls explain why do we select in this case, is it because we are assuming a random selection of two points so as to say ?

If you are asking about how to solve the bold-faced problem about 10 lines in the plane, that's another question. I would suggest just thinking about that question more and perhaps then posting another question here on MSE. But I'll warn you that it appears to be a badly formulated question. What if the ten lines are $y=mx$ for $m=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$? Then there's just one intersection point no matter which $2$ of those $10$ lines you select, namely the point $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

The question is unclear to me. For example, if the lines are all parallel to one another, there will be no intersection points !

@LeeMosher thanks I know sorry it had that sort of badly formulated questions it is more on the pretext that student will surely understand the crux of the problem itself

@trueblueanil I gave the reason in a comment above, its sadly like that
